# I0T agent performance Query

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Hi I am working on a project where I am calculation throughput of IoT agent. I need throughput 1000/s I wanted to know hardware statistic and configuration detail of IoT agent to achieve throughput 1000/s.

Answer (score 1):

According to the FIWARE [Load Test Reports](https://github.com/FIWARE/load-tests), you can achieve that throughput in Orion with a relatively small environment.

| Environment | Orion-LD | Orion-LD-TRoE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tiny | ~1800 req/s | ~1400 req/s |
| small | ~3500 req/s | ~2800 req/s |
| mid | ~12 000 req/s | ~9900 req/s |
| large | ~26 000 req/s | ~23 000 req/s |

Where:

- Tiny - 1 CPU / 6 GB RAM Orion-LD, 4 CPU / 16 GB RAM Mongo-DB
- Small - 2 CPU / 12 GB RAM Orion-LD, 8 CPU / 32 GB RAM Mongo-DB
- Mid - 8 CPU / 48 GB RAM Orion-LD, 30 CPU / 48 GB RAM Mongo-DB
- Large - 16 CPU / 96 GB RAM Orion-LD, 60 CPU / 96 GB RAM Mongo-DB

Of course, it may be the IoT Agent which is the bottleneck, so you'll need to investigate that as well, but this should be a reasonable baseline result.

Comment: The table misses Orion column

Comment: The README of that repository states _Gatling load tests to run against FIWARE Components that implement the **NGSI-LD** API._ Since Orion classic implements NGSI-v2 not NGSI-LD is isn't included in the comparison.

Comment: Maybe the repository should be renamed to ngsild-load-tests? The current name (load-tests) is somehow confusing (it seems it would include all kind of tests related with FIWARE...)